# Access & Re-use model formula (R)

Tags: r, model, glm, lm

I want to automate the following procedure.

1. Fit a (lm /glm) model using `step()`.
2. Extract the variables in the outcome model of (1), e.g., (X1+X2) as in `Y~X1+X2`
3. Re-use the model from (1) in a new lm/glm (plus some new variables).

I understand model formulas can be accessed using `model$call` or `model$terms` where '`model`' is the model from, e.g.

```
model <- lm(Y~X1+X2)
```

But I do not manage to extract it properly and re-ruse it in a new model, such as:

```
model2 <- lm(paste('Z~',model$call[[2]],'+X3',sep=""))
```

Seems to need work on model$call, but I am not sure about the structure of the array and how to collapse it. Thanks.

Comment: Seems useful at first glance, thks.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you haven't completely described your problem, which makes it difficult to answer. Try being much more concrete. Run through a specific example, with the actual code used in each step.

Comment: based on what you have said before, and @liuminzhao's comment, you are looking for `model2 <- update(model,Z~.+X3)`.  @DWin's solution below looks more complicated than it needs to be, since much of the `update()` machinery automatically extracts the formula and updates it.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you new formul objects. Whether they work properly may still be in question since they have associated environments and you have not provided a dataset for testing. Starting with the example on hte update.formula page:

```
> ## Annette Dobson (1990) "An Introduction to Generalized Linear Models".
> ## Page 9: Plant Weight Data.
> ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
> trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
> group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl", "Trt"))
> weight <- c(ctl, trt)
> lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
> update.formula(lm.D9$call[[2]], .~.)
weight ~ group  # Just to make sure that we got something sensible.
<environment: 0x1212230b0>
> update.formula(lm.D9$call[[2]], Z~.)
Z ~ group
<environment: 0x102799fc8>
```

Seems to work on my test case using a random permutation of `weight`:

```
> Z <- sample(weight)
> lm(update.formula(lm.D9$call[[2]], Z~.), data.frame(Z=Z, group=group) )

Call:
lm(formula = update.formula(lm.D9$call[[2]], Z ~ .), data = data.frame(Z = Z, 
    group = group))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     groupTrt  
      4.711        0.271
```

Comment: Thanks to all: update does the trick to my original question.